# React.Js: Styling from React components or pure HTML

Tags: reactjs

I just began my web app in order to learn React.Js and I was wondering, based on the many examples I saw in the internet, if it is better to use `react-bootstrap` components or use pure HTML?

Like for the NavBar, should I use `import { NavBar } from 'react-bootstrap';` and use the component or use pure html such as `<div class="navbar"><div/>`. It's just that if I wanna personalize the design of it, like the CSS, how does it works with react?

Thank you for your time

Comment: just in case, there are dozens of bootstrap type of libraries out there.. semantic, foundation, small ones like bulma, etc, and most of them also have their react ports

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about now if I want to custom them in a certain way? on some points?

Comment: Hi,  the comment became to big to be posted as a comment, so I pasted it in as an answer below

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that there is no single way of styling components in react.

If you'd like to go with the simpliest solution you could just have you good old `style.css` file having all styles you need. Include it in your `index.html` and you are done.

Other ways would include `css-modules`, js styling libraries like `aphrodite` or `iridium`, solutions like `jss`, or solutions like `styled-components`.

In developing my personal project I've gone through all possible ways of stylings (except for jss), starting with keeping a separate scss project just for styling, than css modules, then aphrodite, and ended up with `styled-components`, which I found to be most practical and easy to work with due to good IDE support (webstorm in my case).

Provided you decided to try out `styled-components` way of.. styling components, this is how you would create a custom styled navbar:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { NavBar } from 'react-bootstrap';

export const MyNavBar = styled(NavBar)`
    background-color: red;
`;

// somewhere...
<MyNavBar />
```

For this to work the NavBar component should accept className prop, which I suppose it does. Maybe you'll have to add !important, depending on the situation.